# Illegal nested type family application (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)

Tags: haskell

In GHC 8.0.1, I'm trying to implement a type-level `Length` function for type-level lists. It compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family Length (l :: [*]) :: Nat where
    Length '[] = Z
    Length (_ ': as) = S (Length as)
```

But if I use `TypeLits`, it doesn't compile:

```
import GHC.TypeLits

type family Length (l :: [*]) :: Nat where
    Length '[] = 0
    Length (_ ': as) = 1 + Length as
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
• Illegal nested type family application ‘1 + Length as’
  (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
• In the equations for closed type family ‘Length1’
  In the type family declaration for ‘Length1’
```

Comment: Turn on `UndecidableInstances` and it ought to work. GHC's termination checker is not particularly sophisticated; using a type family on the RHS of another type family is one of the things that's forbidden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to turn on [`UndecideableInstances`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XUndecidableInstances). This extension lifts a bunch of restrictions whose presence ensures that compilation will always terminate. One of these has to do with type families. In your first example, the outer term on the RHS is an actual type, not another call to a type function. On the other hand, in the your second example, the RHS is entirely a call to the type function `(+)` (not to be mistaken with the value level function of the same name).

GHC complains because it can't tell what you wrote ever terminates. In fact, minor variations of it don't:

```
type family Length (l :: [*]) :: Nat where
    Length '[] = 0
    Length (a ': as) = 1 + Length (a ': as)
```

Comment: To be fair, it's not the call to `+` that makes your example non-terminating, it's the recursive call to `Length` on a non-smaller argument. GHC rejects nested type families because it can't be certain `+` doesn't mutually-recursively call `Length` in a way that produces non-termination. Not for any principled reason - just because GHC doesn't feature a very smart termination checker. A better (read: _more complex_) system would accept the OP's definition but not your one.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't ever pondered this too deeply - your comment sure is helpful.